Select all checkboxes, when clicking on the header checkbox and preserve it on applying pagination in React js using UDS library
I have a table and checkbox using UDS library in my react application. On navigating to each page, API is calling and data is reloading each time. Requirement is preserve the selected data in each page, also on header checkbox clicked, select all data displayed in that page and preserve all checked data on applying pagination.InvoiceContext is using for preserving data. Now data is preserving while navigating to each age, but all data is not checked, when selecting header checkbox. Code is given below:
 const { state: checkboxState, dispatch: checkboxContextDispatch } = useCheckboxContext();
      const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
      const selectedIds = checkboxState.selectedIds || []
      const selectedIdsRef = useRef(selectedIds);
      const [indeterminate, setIndeterminate] = useState(false);
      const [selectedId, setSelectedIds] = useState<Number[]>(checkboxState.selectedIds || []);
     
useEffect(() => {
        setSelectedIds(checkboxState.selectedIds || []);
        console.log(selectedIds, 'selectedIds');
      }, [checkboxState.selectedIds]);
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
        selectedIdsRef.current = selectedIds;
      }, [selectedIds]);
    
      const onCheckboxClick = (e: any, item: any) => {
        if(item === null || item === undefined) return;
        setSelectedItems(prevSelectedItems => {
          let newSelectedItems;
      
          if (prevSelectedItems.some(selectedItem => selectedItem.invoiceNumber === item.invoiceNumber)) {
            // If the item is already selected, remove it from the selected items
            newSelectedItems = prevSelectedItems.filter(selectedItem => selectedItem.invoiceNumber !== item.invoiceNumber);
          } else {
            // If the item is not selected, add it to the selected items
            newSelectedItems = [...prevSelectedItems, item];
          }
      
          // Update the other state variables based on the new selectedItems
          checkboxContextDispatch({ type: 'TOGGLE_SELECTION', payload: newSelectedItems });
          if (newSelectedItems?.length === 0) setOpen(false);
          setChecked(newSelectedItems?.length > 0);
          setSelectedIds(newSelectedItems?.map((item: any) => item?.invoiceNumber));
          setSelectedCount(newSelectedItems?.length);
          setFilterApply(newSelectedItems?.length > 0);
      
          return newSelectedItems;
        });
      };
    
      const onHeaderCheckboxClick = (e: any) => {
        const newChecked = e.target.checked;
        setChecked(newChecked);
      
        if(newChecked) {
          // Select all items on the current page
          const currentPageInvoiceNumbers = modifiedItems.map((item: any) => item.invoiceNumber);
          setSelectedItems(modifiedItems);
          setSelectedCount(currentPageInvoiceNumbers.length);
          setFilterApply(true);
          setSelectedIds(currentPageInvoiceNumbers);
          selectedIdsRef.current = currentPageInvoiceNumbers;
        } else {
          // Deselect all items
          setSelectedItems([]);
          setSelectedIds([]);
          setSelectedCount(0);
          setFilterApply(false);
          selectedIdsRef.current = [];
        }   
      };
    
          const columns: Column<InvoiceDetails>[] = [
            {
              id: 'checkboxColumn',
              hideFromMenu: true,
              label: (
                
                <div>
                 <Checkbox 
                dense 
                checked={checked} indeterminate={indeterminate}
              onClick={(e) =>onHeaderCheckboxClick(e)}
              />
              </div>
              ),
              value: (invoiceList: InvoiceDetails) => (
                <div>
                <Checkbox dense checked={selectedIdsRef.current.some(selectedId=> selectedId.invoiceNumber === invoiceList.invoiceNumber)}
                onClick={(e) => onCheckboxClick(e, invoiceList)} />
              </div>
              ),
            },

